# Angular Wordpress REST API - How to create a post with new tags (combine Observables)?

Tags: angular, rxjs, wordpress-rest-api

I have an Angular application that talks to Wordpress REST API. The app needs to create a new post as well as 0-3 new tags with it. I'm saying 0 because in this instance tags are optional. If the user decides to include tags, allow no more than 3 of them. My app works similarly to StackOverflow in that instead of dealing with posts and comments, I will be referring to "questions" and "answers".

The process is as follow:

1. User types in title, body and optional tags for the new "question" in the template. Tags will be typed like `tag-name-1,tag-name2`
2. A button `(click)="saveQuestion(title.value, tags.value)"` triggers a function call to the component.
3. In the component the following piece of code exists:

   ```
   saveQuestion(title: string, tags: string) {

       // value is now an array of strings: ["tag-name-1","tag-name-2"]
       let splittedTags = tags.split(",");

       let tagData = [];

       for (let i = 0; i < splittedTags.length; i++) {
           // value is now [{"name": "tag-name-1"}, {"name": "tag-name-2"}]
           tagData.push({"name": splittedTags[i]});
       }

       // component has an empty array variable called tempArray = [];
       for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
           if (i == 3) { break; }
           // use Tag interface to type the code
           this.questionService.addTag(tagData[i] as Tag)
               .subscribe(tagResponse => {
               this.tempArray.push(tagResponse.id)
           })
       }

       // IMPORTANT: this returns an empty array variable when we need an array of numbers
       console.log("tempArray: " + JSON.stringify(this.tempArray));

       // get title and content from the template
       // tempArray should be an array of strings, which we got from previous loop of subscribe() methods
       let questionData = {
           "date": new Date().toJSON(),      
           "status": "publish",
           "title": title,
           "content": this.html,
           "tags": this.tempArray
       }

       this.questionService.addQuestion(questionData as NewQuestion)
           .subscribe(response => { console.log(response) })

   }
   ```

So we start by capturing the tag name string `"tag-name-1,tag-name-2"` from the template, after which we put it into an array of objects. Then we call service's addTag() function (as many times as there were tags) which calls the  Wordpress REST API and creates a new tag:

```
private questionsUrl = 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2';

httpOptionsAuth = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa("username:password")}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
}

addTag(tag: Tag): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<Tag>(`${this.questionsUrl}/tags`, tag,
    this.httpOptionsAuth)
}
```

Calling the `/tags` API gives us in return the number IDs for the newly created tags. We need to put those number IDs into a an array and then finally call the service's `addQuestion()` method:

```
addQuestion(newquestion: NewQuestion): Observable<NewQuestion> {
    return this.http.post<NewQuestion>(`${this.questionsUrl}/posts`, newquestion,
      this.httpOptionsAuth);
}
```

My question in short is: is there a handy RxJS operator that could take care of combining the Observables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
saveQuestion(title: string, tags: string) {

  // value is now an array of strings: ["tag-name-1","tag-name-2"]
  let splittedTags = tags.split(",");

  from(splittedTags)
    .pipe(
      take(3), // <-- take first 3 tags max
      map((tag) => ({"name": tag})), // <-- map tag string to Tag
      mergeMap( // <-- save tags and extract returned id from responses
        (tag) => this.questionService.addTag(tag as Tag).pipe(
          map((tagResponse) => tagResponse.id)
        )
      ),
      toArray(), // <-- group returned ids into one array
      concatMap( // <-- final save request
        (tagIds) => {
          const questionData = {
            "date": new Date().toJSON(),      
            "status": "publish",
            "title": title,
            "content": this.html,
            "tags": tagIds
          }

          return this.questionService.addQuestion(questionData as NewQuestion)
        }
      )
    )
    .subscribe(console.log);
 }
```

Cheers

Comment: In your code you are stating `tagData[i] as Tag`. What is that `i` variable you are referring to? Could you please edit your answer and show the entire `saveQuestion()` method. I tried to make an edit to your answer, so I changed the aforementioned into `.addTag(tagData as any)`. The `/tags` API gave me an error stating: `Missing parameter(s): name`.

Comment: I updated the answer including the full functionality of the orginal `saveQuestion` method. The `tagData[i] as Tag` was an error due to the copy paste from your code, it should've said `tag as Tag`, where `tag` is the parameter from the `mergeMap` function.  Since I cannot test the code, it may contain more bugs.

Comment: Yes, the latest edit certainly contains a bug. Your code now takes the tags string from template, e.g. `tag-1,tag-2,tag-3` and sends that string THREE TIMES to the services `addTag()` function, which returns an error `"A term with the name provided already exists in this taxonomy."`. This means that for the first time, the tag actually gets successfully added to the Wordpress API, but the following two times give an error as the tag already exists.

Comment: Now it should be fixed, I was assigning `"name"` to `tags` instead of `tag` in the first map.

Comment: Many thanks, your code works nicely!